# Restore/Import Managed Metadata from another SP 2013 Farm

Tags: 2013, managed-metadata, backup, database, import

My situation:

- SP2013 Farm A: Managed Metadata Service Application with database named "ManagedMetadataDB"
- SP2013 Farm B: Managed Metadata Service Application with database named "ManagedMetadataDB"

Same naming convention. I need to backup and restore the database from Farm A onto Farm B. I want the two applications to look identical, so I need to *substitute* Farm B database.

Which is the best way to do it?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To move the MMS from One server to other please follow the below steps.

To export:

```
$mmsAppId= "App ID Guid Placeholder"

$mmsproxy = Get-SPServiceApplicationProxy -Identity "Proxy ID Guid Placeholder"

Export-SPMetadataWebServicePartitionData -Identity $mmsAppId -ServiceProxy $mmsproxy -Path "Path to save Exported file placeholder"
```

To import:

```
$mmsAppId= "App ID Guid Placeholder"

$mmsproxy = Get-SPServiceApplicationProxy -Identity "Proxy ID Guid Placeholder"

Import-SPMetadataWebServicePartitionData -Identity $mmsAppId -ServiceProxy $mmsproxy -Path "Exported file’s path placeholder" -OverwriteExisting;
```

[Read this blog to complete steps.](http://underthehood.ironworks.com/2011/10/sharepoint-2010-how-to-backuprestore-managed-metadata-from-one-farmenvironment-to-another.html)

Comment: Isn't there any ways to do it throught database backup and restore?

Comment: We tried the above method and it works for us.check this one http://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/SP2010-Managed-Metadata-MovingCopying-MMS-Instances-Term-Stores-between-Environments

Comment: Thank you for you reply, the link is well explained but it says "go through the process of creating an MMS instance except make sure you use the name of the database that you restored", which is not my situation... I already have the service app, but I'll manage the situation your way!